# ERROR: Could not build wheels for sktime, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, sktime

Encountering this problem when using -

```
$pip install sktime==0.4.1
```

More information -

> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a
> problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for sktime   Running
> setup.py clean for sktime Failed to build sktime ERROR: Could not
> build wheels for sktime, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried -

```
$python -m pip install sktime==0.4.1
$--no-binary :all:pip install sktime==0.4.1 --no-binary :all:
```

But they didn't worked.

Comment: What platform are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
pip install --upgrade statsmodels
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... .

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I kind of like your edit, which turns a rethoric question into something more assertive. But "Try ..." still has a lot of "I do not know whether it helps, I won't explain anything, all is on your own head." vibe. The initial question could also be read as a proposal to make a debugging experiment, which is meant to yield information and depending on that, one of several actual solutions can bew selected; i.e. it could indeed be a comment menat as the first step on finding a solution. Admittedly, that is a little forced. Point is, I like neither "Did you ...?" nor "Try ...".